# Comparison between variables & change label colour

Tags: ios

I've a `TableView` which is containing two variable on each row and it is refreshing every 2 seconds via getting data from the server. I want to change the labels colour every update if it is higher or lower in red or green. So please how can I do that? While I know how to change the label colour but don't know how to make the compression between each 2 seconds.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"comCell";

comTableViewCell *cell = (comTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *parts = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"comTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    cell = [parts objectAtIndex:0];
}

id rowObject = [data1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[cell.lblType setText:[rowObject objectForKey:@"strSymbol"]];
[cell.lblOffer setText:[rowObject objectForKey:@"strOffer"]];
[cell.lblBid setText:[rowObject objectForKey:@"strBid"]];

cell.lblType.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0f];
cell.lblOffer.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0f];
cell.lblBid.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0f];

cell.lblType.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
cell.lblOffer.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
cell.lblBid.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


return cell;
}
```

Data result:

```
        {
    strBid = "1.29158";
    strOffer = "1.29258";
    strSymbol = "USD/EUR";
},
    {
    strBid = "98.964";
    strOffer = "99.004";
    strSymbol = "AUD/JPY";
},
    {
    strBid = "11.2472";
    strOffer = "11.2972";
    strSymbol = "USD/ZAR";
}
```

Update:

```
    data2 = data1;

    id rowObject2 = [data2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *new_offer = [rowObject2 objectForKey:@"strOffer"];

    if (data2 != nil) {

        id old_rowObject = [data2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSString *old_offer = [old_rowObject objectForKey:@"strOffer"];

        if ([new_offer doubleValue] > [old_offer doubleValue]) {

            cell.lblOffer.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            cell.lblBid.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        }

        else if ([new_offer doubleValue] == [old_offer doubleValue]) {

            cell.lblOffer.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            cell.lblBid.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }

        else {

            cell.lblOffer.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
            cell.lblBid.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        }

    } else {
        // first time getting data.
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Please share the code where you update your data.

Comment: I'm updateing my data on `data1` array. I will share the code

Comment: Also the did start parsing method.

Comment: @hasan83 could you please tell me what is the best way to save the data and check?

Comment: It's there in my answer. just put old data in another nsmutablearray before you read new one. as in code.

Comment: Create a github project. and I will download it and edit it.

Comment: My bad you are parsing json not xml.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

move this line `data2 = data1;` to the place you start parse the json. before the code you use to parse.

**Old Post:**

```
- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    old_data = data1;  <<-- saves data here!
    data1 = [[…. alloc] init]; 
}

id rowObject = [data1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *new_offer = [rowObject objectForKey:@"strOffer"];

if (old_data != nil) {
    id old_rowObject = [old_data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    NSString *old_offer = [old_rowObject objectForKey:@"strOffer"];

    if ([new_offer doubleValue] > [old_offer doubleValue]) {
     // set colour here.
    } else {
     // and here.
    }
} else {
    // first time getting data.
}
```

Comment: I don't think he wants to compare `strOffer` to `strBid`. I think he wants to compare the value of `strOffer` 2 seconds ago to the value of `strOffer` now.

Comment: Your updated answer assumes that the row you get from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` was the row from the same `indexPath`, which is frequently not true.

Comment: You are right. But, looks like our friend here don't store the old data. I do something else.

Comment: I'm sorry @IanMacDonald is right I want to compare the value of strOffer 2 seconds ago to the value of strOffer now.

Comment: @CAN You need to store the old data if you want to compare it to the new data.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy I think I should store it and then compare and overwrite. Could you please show me an easy way?

Comment: @CAN Try to solve it yourself first. If you have trouble, post a question about the issue you are having with it.

Comment: @hasan83 I always get the new_offer & old_offer same. Where could be the issue?